# Service should be init in its parent controller or itself?

Tags: angularjs, web

I have a web app layout like below screenshot.
It has several menus, and in each menu we have several tabs on the left sidebar:
[image]
if some configuration in one tab is wrong, I want to get notified even i was opening another tab.

Currently for each tabs, i have 1 service map to it, e.g. tab1 -> tab1Service, tab2 -> tab2Service.
Each service will have an init method to initial the data for each tab(tabCtrl), and it will only be called once i click that tab.

So here is the question:
If i want to got notified which tab has an error when i first go into this menu, i have to call that tabService init in the parent controller also, otherwise the error icon won't be displayed.
If i am going to do like this, once i refresh the page on a sub tab, the init method will be call twice consecutively, which isn't very good.

Does anyone know is there a better solution for this? I think it should be a common case in web development, hope someone could help me on this.

Comment: why don't you only initialise all tab services at the start of the app? That way you only call it once and you can immediately know if one tab has an error

Comment: What does the tabService do? Sounds like you have an XY problem. **All** UI concerns in Angular should be in the directive/controller or component layers and should not be in the service ones.

Comment: @DanPantry I have defined several services mapping to each tab. The major thing each tab service do is to manipulate the data in that tab. e.g. Tab1Service will init the data for content in tab1.

Comment: That seems like a bad idea, @huanfeng. Services are singletons, so you should make them immutable and stateless where possible. Your UI state belongs in your controller.